# How to swap columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I  am trying to swap to columns only in tablet version, but I am fail to do this.
I am sharing my code here. please look through it.

```
    <section class="block">
        <div class="copyright container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row reorder-sm reorder-lg">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm visible-lg text-center-sm text-left-md text-left-lg col-sm-push-12"><p >&copy; 2015 copy text</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm visible-lg text-center-sm text-right-md text-right-lg col-sm-pull-12"><a href="">Terms</a>|<a href="">Privacy</a>|<a href="">Cookies</a>  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

But this is not pulling my divs.

Can anybody help me ?

Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ytvfocwd/

Comment: I think you need to explain what exactly you want to do in clear words. What do you mean by it's not pulling your divs? With the number of restrictions you have put through bs classes in your divs, in my view, they are certainly working fine. Please explain, what is the behavior that you are expecting from above mentioned fiddle?

Comment: Hi @Patel , what I need is change the order of the div in tablet only. eg: copy text to bottom and the links to up.

Comment: I don't think Bootstrap classes can do that. You would need to use some Javascript for swapping divs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the push/pull classes:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">1 2 3 </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the columns will collapse in the opposite order at break points.

This is a tip provided here: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-might-not-know

Hope this helps!